# Вход в аккаунт с помощью VK API

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Необходимо войти в аккаунт вк с помощью Java, и отправлять сообщения друзьям, как можно было бы реализовать это? Или лучше какие библиотеки использовать для java и тд? Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вот метод для отправки сообщения https://vk.com/dev/messages.send. Там же есть и описание как токен получить. И вот ещё с хабра про то, что отправить, вроде, нельзя https://m.habr.com/ru/post/446172/

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а можно поподробнее? И с помощью какого java пакета лучше использовать?

Comment: Подробнее не могу - не занимался таким. Если кратко - вам надо получить токен, авторизовавшись. Возможно, понадобится этап с браузером, который потом вам токен вернёт. Потом этот токен прикрепляете к запросам API. Надо ли использовать SDK - тот ещё вопрос. Зависит от задачи. По первой ссылке из первого коммента можно найти такое SDK - https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK. Однако не уверен, что вы там сможете получить нужный токен. И не уверен, что без личного разрешения от VK вы сможете отправлять сообщения.